# Why the "Landscape" position does not resize the LongListSelector?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

Why when I put the phone in Landscape position, LongListSelectornão resizes?

Following image:
[image: Landscape]

Following my `XAML`:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <phone:LongListSelector Name="lstConsPais"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    LayoutMode="List" 
    IsGroupingEnabled="False"
    Width="456" SelectionChanged="lstConsPais_SelectionChanged">
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border BorderBrush="#111" Margin="0, 10, 0, 0" BorderThickness="0,0,0,2">
                            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Height="100" Width="100"  Source="{Binding NomeImgBandeira}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding NomePais}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextGroupHeaderStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="15,25,0,0" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>
        </Grid>
```

**I wanted him to fill the entire screen.**

more or less like this:

[image]

**but I do not want to tamper with the "width", I want "automatic"**

Comment: Get rid of `VerticalAlignment="Top"`, that is if I'm understanding your question correctly...

Comment: Then I'm not understanding your question correctly :P

Comment: Ah ok, so what you should be asking is how to deal with change from Portrait to Landscape mode as you're wanting to support [SupportedOrientations="PortraitOrLandscape"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207002(v=vs.105).aspx) in which case you need to change some properties of your layout based on that condition. For that scenario you'll want to implement `VisualStateManager` to alter your layout based on which Orientation it's in, which there's multiple [tutorials](http://wp.qmatteoq.com/how-to-manage-orientation-in-windows-phone-using-visualstatemanager/) for.